# shortcut for creating a Map from a List in groovy?

Tags: java, collections, groovy, expandometaclass

I'd like some sorthand for this:

```
Map rowToMap(row) {
    def rowMap = [:];
    row.columns.each{ rowMap[it.name] = it.val }
    return rowMap;
}
```

given the way the GDK stuff is, I'd expect to be able to do something like:

```
Map rowToMap(row) {
    row.columns.collectMap{ [it.name,it.val] }
}
```

but I haven't seen anything in the docs... am I missing something? or am I just way too lazy?

Comment: Amir's comment is now the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4484958/27561

Answer (score 147, accepted):

I've recently came across the need to do exactly that: converting a list into a map. This question was posted before Groovy version 1.7.9 came out, so the method [`collectEntries`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#collectEntries(java.lang.Iterable,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) didn't exist yet. It works exactly as the `collectMap` method [that was proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538/shortcut-for-creating-a-map-from-a-list-in-groovy/19077#19077):

```
Map rowToMap(row) {
    row.columns.collectEntries{[it.name, it.val]}
}
```

If for some reason you are stuck with an older Groovy version, the [`inject`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#inject(java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) method can also be used (as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538/shortcut-for-creating-a-map-from-a-list-in-groovy/198614#198614)). This is a slightly modified version that takes only one expression inside the closure (just for the sake of character saving!):

```
Map rowToMap(row) {
    row.columns.inject([:]) {map, col -> map << [(col.name): col.val]}
}
```

The `+` operator can also be used instead of the `<<`.

Answer (score 32):

Check out "inject".  Real functional programming wonks call it "fold".

```
columns.inject([:]) { memo, entry ->
    memo[entry.name] = entry.val
    return memo
}
```

And, while you're at it, you probably want to define methods as Categories instead of right on the metaClass.  That way, you can define it once for all Collections:

```
class PropertyMapCategory {
    static Map mapProperty(Collection c, String keyParam, String valParam) {
        return c.inject([:]) { memo, entry ->
            memo[entry[keyParam]] = entry[valParam]
            return memo
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
use(PropertyMapCategory) {
    println columns.mapProperty('name', 'val')
}
```

Comment: I guess it's named inject in Groovy as it might have been inspired by inject:into: in Smalltalk:  

| list sum |  
list := OrderedCollection new add: 1; add: 2; add: 3; yourself.  
sum := list inject: 0 into: [ :a :b | a + b ].  
Transcript cr; show: sum.  "prints 6"

Answer (score 13):

Was the [groupBy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#groupBy(java.lang.Iterable,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) method not available when this question was asked?

Comment: Seems like no - it's since 1.8.1, 2011. The question was asked in 2008.
But in any case, groupBy is now the way to go indeed.

Comment: As you can see in the documentation for groupBy, it basically groups elements into groups, where each group contains element matching a certain key.
Hence, its return type is ```Map<K, List<V>>``` It seems that the OP is looking for a method with return type ```Map<K, V>```, so groupBy does not work in this case.

Answer (score 11):

If what you need is a simple key-value pair, then the method `collectEntries` should suffice. For example

```
def names = ['Foo', 'Bar']
def firstAlphabetVsName = names.collectEntries {[it.charAt(0), it]} // [F:Foo, B:Bar]
```

But if you want a structure similar to a Multimap, in which there are multiple values per key, then you'd want to use the `groupBy` method

```
def names = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fooey']
def firstAlphabetVsNames = names.groupBy { it.charAt(0) } // [F:[Foo, Fooey], B:[Bar]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Also, if you're use google collections (http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/), you can do something like this:

```
  map = Maps.uniqueIndex(list, Functions.identity());
```

Answer (score 5):

ok... I've played with this a little more and I think this is a pretty cool method...

```
def collectMap = {Closure callback->
    def map = [:]
    delegate.each {
        def r = callback.call(it)
        map[r[0]] = r[1]
    }
    return map
}
ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()
Collection.metaClass.collectMap = collectMap
Map.metaClass.collectMap = collectMap
```

now any subclass of Map or Collection have this method...

here I use it to reverse the key/value in a Map

```
[1:2, 3:4].collectMap{[it.value, it.key]} == [2:1, 4:3]
```

and here I use it to create a map from a list

```
[1,2].collectMap{[it,it]} == [1:1, 2:2]
```

now I just pop this into a class that gets called as my app is starting and this method is available throughout my code.

EDIT:

to add the method to all arrays...

```
Object[].metaClass.collectMap = collectMap
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything built in... but using the ExpandoMetaClass I can do this:

```
ArrayList.metaClass.collectMap = {Closure callback->
    def map = [:]
    delegate.each {
        def r = callback.call(it)
        map[r[0]] = r[1]
    }
    return map
}
```

this adds the collectMap method to all ArrayLists... I'm not sure why adding it to List or Collection didn't work.. I guess that's for another question... but now I can do this...

```
assert ["foo":"oof", "42":"24", "bar":"rab"] ==
            ["foo", "42", "bar"].collectMap { return [it, it.reverse()] }
```

from List to calculated Map with one closure... exactly what I was looking for.

Edit: the reason I couldn't add the method to the interfaces List and Collection was because I did not do this:

```
List.metaClass.enableGlobally()
```

after that method call, you can add methods to interfaces.. which in this case means my collectMap method will work on ranges like this:

```
(0..2).collectMap{[it, it*2]}
```

which yields the map: [0:0, 1:2, 2:4]

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
// setup
class Pair { 
    String k; 
    String v; 
    public Pair(def k, def v) { this.k = k ; this.v = v; }
}
def list = [ new Pair('a', 'b'), new Pair('c', 'd') ]

// the idea
def map = [:]
list.each{ it -> map.putAt(it.k, it.v) }

// verify
println map['c']
```

Comment: That's basically the same as in my question... I just had map[it.k] = it.v instead of .putAt

I was looking for a one liner.