# Groovy / Grails: Create Map from Lists

Tags: grails, groovy

I have two lists:

```
 def courseList  = PublicTraining.executeQuery(
     "SELECT t.course.id, t.course.name from PublicTraining AS t")
 def cityList  = PublicTraining.executeQuery(
     "SELECT t.venue.city.id, t.venue.city.name from PublicTraining AS t")
```

and:

```
courseList  = [[1, weblogic], [2, ajax]]
cityList   = [[1, City1], [2, City2]]
```

How can I create a `Map` which looks like this?

```
resultMap = ['Course':[['1', 'weblogic'],['2', 'ajax']], 'City':[['1','City1'],
    ['2','City2']] ]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [shortcut for creating a Map from a List in groovy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538/shortcut-for-creating-a-map-from-a-list-in-groovy)

Comment: If you have the two list why don't you just create the map `resultMap = ['Course' : courseList, 'City' : cityList]` I think, I'm missing something on the question.....

Comment: or in one row 

resultMap = [ Course: PublicTraining.executeQuery(
     "SELECT t.course.id, t.course.name from PublicTraining AS t"), City: PublicTraining.executeQuery(
     "SELECT t.venue.city.id, t.venue.city.name from PublicTraining AS t") ]